# Android Data Binding mCallback is always null

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I've been experimenting with the Android data binding library, folllowing the google developer guide. But even with following their code exactly `notifyPropertyChanged()` never works.

mCallbacks in the `BaseObservable` is always null. I've debugged the code as the binding is set up and `addOnPropertyChangedCallback` is called and mCallbacks is set, but for some reason this reference has been lost by the time you get round to calling `notifyPropertyChanged()`.

There's probably something I'm missing so any help would be much appreciated!

Code:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TestModel mTestModel;
ActivityTestBinding mBinding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_test);
    mTestModel = new TestModel("Test", "User");
    mBinding.setTestModel(mTestModel);

    mBinding.ratingBtnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mTestModel.setFirstName("New");
            mTestModel.setLastName("WOOOOORKS");
            mBinding.notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName);
        }
    });
}}


public class TestModel extends BaseObservable {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public TestModel(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Bindable
public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

@Bindable
public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}}
```

Layout:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >


    <data>
        <variable
            name="testModel"
            type="com.boundless.happymeter.model.TestModel"
            />
    </data>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{testModel.firstName}"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{testModel.lastName}"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rating_btn_update"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="Update"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


</layout>
```

Note:
It is possible to force the binding by using mBinding.invalidateAll() - but this is quite an ugly soloution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `executePendingBindings()`, it will execute all the binding which are changed and need to update.

```
binding.executePendingBindings();
```

Other solution is that you can use `notifyPropertyChanged();` in all setter methods

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName);
}
```

Comment: That worked a charm! I was using mBinding.notifyPropertyChanged (instead of the super method in BaseObservable) so the callback was of course null, Thanks!